# Print the content of a listview using Javafx print API

Tags: javafx-8

I'm trying to print a list of images contained in a **listview**.

Here's the code :

```
PrinterJob job=PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(listview.getScene().getWindow())){
    boolean success = job.printPage(listview);

    System.out.println(success);
    if (success) {
        job.endJob(); 
    }

}
```

The thing is that I get an empty page each time I try to print it and the value of the variable "success" is "true"!

why so ? and how can I print this list knowing that it contains a list of barcode images that I want to print using a thermal printer.

Please help !